# Review merge actions with KDiff after successful automated solving of merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict, kdiff3

I use KDiff as a merge tool with Git. After an unsuccessful Git Merge, I started solving conflicts for individual files with git mergetool, which calls KDiff as specified in my config.

However for one file it said "Number of conflicts : x. Number of conflicts automatically solved : x. Remaining conflicts : 0" or something to that effect. Clicking ok return to the console which went to the next file.

Upon reviewing the result I was not happy with it. I now want to know if it is possible to reopen KDiff with the standard 3-way merge view, even if I can't make edits, just to see how it has interpreted and done things in detail.

EDIT : Here's a possible partial solution which has the first part missing :

- Set KDiff to not close upon automatically solving all conflicts - or otherwise not solve conflicts automatically at all (first option obviously preferred, but found some stack overflow topics on how to do the second like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321472/how-could-i-force-mergetool-gui-kdiff3-to-be-always-shown)). Will investigate if the first option is possible at all, currently not implemented.
- Use the command `git checkout -m <path/to/file.extension>` to revert the file to its post-merge conflicting state (with conflict tags and everything, such that the file will be marked as in "unresolved conflict" state or whatever and then calling `git mergetool  <path/to/file.extension>` will run KDiff on that file again, this time with the new setting)

Comment: After your edit, what part is still missing?

Comment: Sorry yes, I specified. Better ?

Comment: I think at this point - based on the answer you posted below - you've solved everything, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321472/how-could-i-force-mergetool-gui-kdiff3-to-be-always-shown/15813064#15813064) does exactly what is needed : auto-merge but not close even if no conflicts are left, such that you can review everything KDiff did.

Now for any file that you have already finished merged, you can use `git checkout -m <path/to/file.extension>` to revert it back into its "merged with unresolved conflicts" state, and then run the modified "KDiff no auto" mergetool.